# SQL user is not used for login

Tags: javascript, mysql, access-denied

My problem is occuring when I try to login to SQL using `user:'root'`, `host: 'localhost'`, `database: 'db'` and `password: ''` ,the console gives error like I didn't define `user`

`[!] SQL Error: Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

My `server.js`:

```
import SQL from 'mysql';


 SQL: {

      host: 'localhost'
      user: 'root'
      password: ''
      database: 'root'

};


function load() {
    var MySQL = SQL.createConnection(SQL)
    MySQL.connect((err) => {
          if(err) {
             console.log(err);
             process.exit(0);
          }
        
          for(var i = 0; i < 250; i++) console.log("\n");
          console.log('Successfuly logged in!');

    });
    
}
load();
```

What can be done to prevent this error?

I am new to SQL and JS so please, don't be harsh on me if it's a stupid question :)

EDIT: I want to mention that I tried changing values of host, user, password and database and whatever I put, it says the same error.

I tried setting some random word for pass, example: `password: 'pass123'`
but the console gives me the same error inluding `using password: NO` part.

What could cause that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `SQL` field isn't a valid object.

Change

```
SQL: {

      host: 'localhost'
      user: 'root'
      password: ''
      database: 'root'

};
```

to

```
credentials = {

      host: 'localhost'
      user: 'root'
      password: ''
      database: 'root'

};
```

Comment: I did what you said and got rid of that error but got a new one: `TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.`

Comment: Oh, sorry. Give the SQL object above a different name. Smth like  credentials. As the name is not different from the import, you try overwriting the import (answer updated) (also change the name in the connect function)

Comment: Which part of connect function should I rename?
EDIT: I changed `SQL.createConnection(SQL)` to `SQL.createConnection(credentials)`
Perfect!